# Java Fatal Exception onClick

Tags: java, android

Hello I am getting strange error when I click my button. It worked fine before: it stopped working and I don't know why. Can you help me out? Here is the code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.bPrisijungti:
            String elpastas = etElpastas.getText().toString();
            String slaptazodis = etSlaptazodis.getText().toString();

            User user = new User(elpastas, slaptazodis,"","","");

            authenticate(user);
            break;
        case R.id.tvRegistracija:
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(registerIntent);
            break;
    }
}
```

I get error on String elpastas...

xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:text="El paštas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etelpastas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Slaptažodis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSlaptazodis"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPrisijungti"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prisijungti" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRegistracija"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Naujas vartotojas"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat :

```
05-25 21:04:57.094    9100-9100/com.tonikamitv.loginregister D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-25 21:04:58.384    9100-9100/com.tonikamitv.loginregister D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-25 21:04:58.384    9100-9100/com.tonikamitv.loginregister W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41241438)
05-25 21:04:58.424    9100-9100/com.tonikamitv.loginregister E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.tonikamitv.loginregister.Login.onClick(Login.java:40)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you define  etElpastas ?

Comment: In Login.java at line 40 is a null

Comment: @+id/etelpastas should be @+id/etElpastas

Comment: what do you mean define? I it declared as string variable.

Comment: Is it properly initialized?

Comment: @trevor thank you I skipped it. I will see if it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done this before onclick.I think this is the root cause.

```
EditText etElpastas=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etelpastas);
```

Comment: Correct answer. I skipped that line.